# Meaning of "deduced A" in the context of type deduction from a call

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

> If `P` is a class and `P` has the form [*simple-template-id*](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.names#nt:simple-template-id), then the transformed `A` can be a derived class `D` of the deduced `A`.

[from **[temp.deduct.call]**4.3](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.call#4.3.sentence-1)

This sentence describes how a function template argument is still valid if it is derived from "deduced `A`", However, there is not solid definition for what "deduced `A`" actually is.

My theory is that deduced `A` is original `P` with template arguments from `A` substituted in, but this would break the rules of type deduction trying to find template arguments to make `A` and deduced `A` identical, as there would be cases with A being a non-reference and deduced `A` being a reference.

Comment: How can deduced `A` be a reference, in light of "If `P` is a reference type, the type referred to by `P` is used for type deduction" ?

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik Sorry, changed to "original P"

Comment: So then, my theory is that "deduced `A`" is transformed `P` with deduced template arguments substituted in. Where "transformed `P`" is the type used in place of `P` for type deduction.

Comment: But then that would not work with forwarding references, as reference collapsing would no longer occur

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik Assuming that "deduced A" is then used as the parameter, forwarding references would no longer work. 
`template<typename T> void f(T&&); f(1); // transformed P is T, A is int, deduced A is int`

Edit: Scratch that, makes sense. Then the template arguments from deduced A are used as the template arguments for the function.

Comment: There's a special case for forwarding references: "If `P` is a forwarding reference and the argument is an lvalue, the type “lvalue reference to `A`” is used in place of `A` for type deduction." So `A` is either `int` or `int&` depending on whether the argument is an rvalue or lvalue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The goal of function template argument deduction is to figure out which particular specialization of a function template should be used in places where the template name is used like a function name. For example, given a function template

```
template <typename T>
void f(T* value) {}
```

when you then have a function call like

```
int* a = &x;
f(a);
```

the name `f` here is not actually the name of a function but the name of a function template. The compiler has to figure out which concrete specialization of the function template this call should actually be calling based on the types of the arguments given in the function call. In other words, it has to figure out which template argument `X` should be used for the template parameter `T` to get to an actual function `f<X>` that could be called here like that. This is a bit of an inverse problem compared to a normal function call. Rather than having to make a list of arguments fit a given signature (by applying conversions), we're now having to make a signature fit a given list of arguments. Another way of looking at it is as trying to deduce template arguments that will make the type of each function parameter match the type of each function call argument. This is what [[temp.deduct.call]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.call#4) is talking about here:

> In general, the deduction process attempts to find template argument values that will make the deduced A identical to A

Taking our example above, given some deduced template argument `X`, the deduced argument type is what we get by substituting our deduced `X` for `T` into our function parameter type `T*` (i.e., the type of argument this function parameter takes). If we deduce `X` to be `int`, substituting `int` for `T` into `T*` makes our deduced argument type come out to be `int*`. Since the deduced argument type `int*` is identical to the type of the actual argument, we've found that the function `f<int>` is what we were looking for.

To make all of this consistent with how normal function calls behave, there are a few corner cases to take care of. In particular with function call arguments of array and function types, where we normally have array-to-pointer and function-to-pointer decay, as well as top-level const. To deal with this, the standard specifies that the argument type `A` we're trying to match is not simply taken to be the type of the corresponding function call argument directly but is first *transformed* by applying the array-to-pointer, function-to-pointer, etc. conversions. This *transformed* `A` is the `A` we're actually trying to make our deduced argument type match. This is just to explain why the standard talks about a "transformed `A`" there. It's not really that important to the question at hand. The transformed `A` is just the function argument type we're actually trying to match.

Now, let's say we have some

```
template <typename T> class B {};
```

and some derived class

```
class D : public B<int> {};
```

When you then have a function template like

```
template <typename T>
void f(const B<T>*) {}
```

and a function call like this

```
D d;
f(&d);
```

there is no template argument `X` you could pick for `T` that would make the deduced argument type `const B<X>*` equal to `D*`. But since `D` is derived from `B<int>`, deducing the template argument to be `int` would nevertheless lead to a function specialization `f<int>` that could take the call. The whole paragraph [[temp.deduct.call]/4.3](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.call#4.3) and especially the sentence from your question

> If `P` is a class and `P` has the form *simple-template-id*, then the transformed `A` can be a derived class `D` of the deduced `A`.

is there to allow exactly this to work…